# Next.js fetching different API end point when using environment variable

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working with next.js 13 for my project. and i got into a wierd behaiviour while fetching data from an API. the below is the code i am working with -

```
    const d = `http://localhost:5000/products/allproducts`
    const e = `${process.env.API_URL}/products/allproducts`

    const response = await fetch(e, {
        cache: 'no-store'
    });
const data: { data: Product[] } = await response.json();
```

when i fetch with url d there is no problem. but when i use url e for fetching i am getting an error in the browser saying

**Unhandled Runtime Error**
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

I tried console logging both d and e which retuned same string. and also the below code returned true in the console.

```
 console.log(`${process.env.API_URL}/products/allproducts` === `http://localhost:5000/products/allproducts`)
```

I also checked the network tab of the browser and i saw it is making request to url - http://localhost:3000/undefined/products/allproducts . what is the probable reason for this